# Share video data between C++ and Python

Tags: c++, python, windows, ipc

I have a USB camera (uEye) which has a C++ interface allowing you to configure some features of the camera. The C++ program can read the image data from the camera and store it somewhere in pre-allocated memory. All of this runs under Windows.

Python with numpy gives me a simple environment to manipulate images and spend some quality time working on my processing algorithms.

What I would like to do is:

1. Use the c++ program to configure the camera and obtain images (at video rate),
2. Pass the data to Python
3. Process the data in Python

I am under the impression that I do not want to embed C++ in Python or Python in C++, as I prefer to have two stand-alone systems (so I can use the camera without the Python stuff, or use the Python stuff without the camera).

What I can find so far are methods to share some data using pipes, sockets, or mapped memory, though it appears to be restricted to small amounts of data or strings. What I can not find, however, is an indication if this is fast enough and something that I should attempt to implement. Should I want to do this?

If this is a bad idea, what would be a better alternative? Embed the Python code in C++ or vice versa? Or ditch Python all together because the savings in development time there do not offset the additional effort in getting the interprocess communication to work?

Comment: The last time I implemented a graphics algorithm in Python (with numpy) was so slow that I had to translate it into C++. The speed improvement was about x20. So if you want to do it real time, maybe you should reconsider.

Comment: I see your point. Perhaps the bottleneck is the processing in python and using a file as transfer medium is fast enough to keep up with the framerate attainable with processing in Python. Then, when the required processing steps have been determined (and I've made some colourful plots with matplotlib), we can think about moving everything to c++. I was just hoping I could skip writing/reading a file from disk and doing the same from memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a [recent post](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/) on the PyPy blog about real-time video processing. In the example they use mplayer to be grab and display video, which might be preferable to trying to interface with your C++ program (assuming it works with your webcam). If not, thinking along those lines a simple solution is to just connect stdout/stdin of your two applications. Also probably a good idea to look at PyPy for video processing.

Comment: Thanks. Let's assume I need to control on board parameters of the camera so mplayer is not an option. Regarding stdin/stdout, does that work with a binary format, or do I need to convert the image data to text and back? Transfer rates are not a possible issue?

Comment: You can pipe binary data around, transfer rates shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say the device has a "C++ interface", I assume it provides a header file + DLL which you can link to and control the device via an API. In such a case, the fastest approach would be to wrap this API in Python (using Swig or other C++-to-Python API tools). This will provide a very low overhead of just a couple of procedure calls, passing the data directly as pointers to memory.

If you don't want to "marry" Python, write yourself a controlling app in C++ too, but I think the fastest and most convenient way of connecting the API to Python is the above.

Comment: The controlling app in C++ already exists. Nevertheless, I got halfway through porting a Linux implementation of the API wrap in Python to Windows when I got stuck as some library did not want to play along (possibly caused by different compilers used for the library and the wrapping??). Thus, I thought it might be easier to use the two existing, working systems (in c++ and in python) and get them to play along, rather than wrapping.